# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema con mi proyecto de Laravel, lo que sucede es que me aparece el error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión" al momento de acceder a cualquier pantalla de mi proyecto, se que es el tema de la base de datos, pero lo que me extraña es que incluso sin acceder a ninguna ventana que requiera alguna conexión con la base de datos me sigue apareciendo el error.

¿No se supone que solo debería mostrármelo cuando intento iniciar sesión o acceder a alguna ruta validada con "Auth"?

Espero que puedan ayudarme, adjunto captura de el error.
[image: Error que aparece en mi formulario para iniciar sesion]

Comment: Hola ADDCCELERATOR,  la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: Me paso lo mismo y me di cuenta que no tenia mi servidor iniciado (wampserver), espero te sirva.

Comment: Revisa que tengas conectada la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el valor

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

por

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

en el fichero `.env`